# Twitter Application Only Authentication PHP OAuth error

Tags: php, curl, twitter, http-headers, twitter-oauth

**Please Note**

A full implementation of a working Twitter Application Only Authentication Oauth PHP library can now be found at the the following github link: [Twitter Application Only Authentication OAuth Php](http://jonhurlock.github.io/Twitter-Application-Only-Authentication-OAuth-PHP/)

---

I'm trying to get my application to authenticate via Twitter's application only authentication. See documentation at the following URL:

[Twitter Developer Documentation fro Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)

I get to step 2 and request a bearer token using the code pasted below. I receive a response that looks like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 15:13:03 GMT 
Status: 200 OK 
X-Frame-Options: DENY 
ETag: "6b7ec13d0ef1e9d8e0b39bec5266ba7b" 
X-Runtime: 0.06008 
Pragma: no-cache 
Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 15:13:03 GMT 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
X-Transaction: 55809f2187d74c8e 
X-MID: 4503f89925628df071cb1d27c3e6953709234b1b 
Expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0 
Set-Cookie: k=10.37.190.122.1363705983314067; path=/; expires=Tue, 26-Mar-13 15:13:03 GMT; domain=.twitter.com 
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoMY3NyZl9pZCIlZTI5MjJmNDI5ODY4MzM0NjAz%250AMzkwZTE2NDY5MzdiNGM6D2NyZWF0ZWRfYXRsKwhV8TWDPQE6B2lkIiU2NzEy%250AZjgzOTNjYjc4NjNhYzgwMjU2Mjc1Yzc0ZDYyMw%253D%253D--22b3f64a757c1f9f3c3ae8df9ee434848c43eee8; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 138 
Server: tfe 
Set-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A136370598331525689; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 19-Mar-2015 15:13:03 UTC

‹«V*ÉÏNÍx‹/©,HU²RJJM,J-RÒQJLNN-.ŽKrÅ±‚|sg(«¢Ê(Ô5*ÝÕÃÂGÕÈ­ÌÃxßÂ²(ÐÄÙ(Í4ØÍÔDÕØ¥2+È³Ô Ô¨Ê7«À«$,+ÛÃ"ß35
```

As you can see the content returned does nto seem to return a json string as described in the documentation

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
...
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 140

{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"}
```

As we can see

```
‹«V*ÉÏNÍx‹/©,HU²RJJM,J-RÒQJLNN-.ŽKrÅ±‚|sg(«¢Ê(Ô5*ÝÕÃÂGÕÈ­ÌÃxßÂ²(ÐÄÙ(Í4ØÍÔDÕØ¥2+È³Ô Ô¨Ê7«À«$,+ÛÃ"ß35
```

is not equal to

```
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"}
```

I was wondering if this could be a possible encoding error or if I am fundamentally doing something wrong with the cURL.

My code is pasted below, any help would be appreciated:

Jon

```
<?php
// from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth
$consumer_key = 'myconsumerkey';
$consumer_secret = 'myconsumersecret';

// step 1
  // step 1.1 - url encode the consumer_key and consumer_secret in accordance with RFC 1738
    $encoded_consumer_key = urlencode($consumer_key);
    $encoded_consumer_secret = urlencode($consumer_secret);
    // step 1.2 - concatinate encoded consumer, a colon character and the encoded consumer secr    et
$bearer_token = $encoded_consumer_key.':'.$encoded_consumer_secret;
    // step 1.3 - base64-encode bearer token
    $base64_encoded_bearer_token = base64_encode($bearer_token);
// step 2
      $url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"; // url to send data to for authentication
        $headers = array( 
            "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1", 
            "Host: api.twitter.com", 
            "User-Agent: my Twitter App v.1",
            //"Authorization: Basic ".$base64_encoded_bearer_token."",
            "Authorization: Basic ".$base64_encoded_bearer_token."",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", 
            "Content-Length: 29",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
        ); 

$ch = curl_init();  // setup a curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  // set url to send to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // set custom headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // send as post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials"); // post body/fields to be sent
$header = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // send custom headers
//$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the curl
curl_close($ch);  // stop curling
?>
```

Comment: I think the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header might be your problem here – you say you accept a gzipped response, but then you don’t know what to do with it … so don’t set that header.

Comment: That was the problem :D Thanks for the response

Comment: This is purely for code readability, but where you use `$bearer_token` as the variable name for `$encoded_consumer_key.':'.$encoded_consumer_secret`, you are actually _requesting_ a bearer token, so a better variable name would be `$credentials` and `$base64cred`. Again, purely for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) in comments:

I think the Accept-Encoding: gzip header might be your problem here – you say you accept a gzipped response, but then you don’t know what to do with it … so don’t set that header. – CBroe

Answer (score 2):

As CBroe said in the comments, removing the header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' will fix.

If you still want to use gzip to speed up the transfer, curl will add the header and automatically ungzip the response for you if you set the option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```